# Unable to open Facebook Messenger to share a video from iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-messenger

I want to share a video from my iOS application in Facebook messenger using the following code:

```
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[self.myViewController getSharingVideoPath]];
FBSDKShareVideo *video = [[FBSDKShareVideo alloc] init];
video.videoURL = videoURL;
FBSDKShareVideoContent *content = [[FBSDKShareVideoContent alloc] init];
content.video = video;
[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:content delegate:nil];
```

This is the output of videoURL:

```
file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/13D19738-5F9E-4C77-A502-0E18F5D09A10/Documents/anonymous/MyApp/144229926301/MyVideo.mov
```

When I run, there is no error but Facebook messenger does not open.

I copied the code from

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios
```

which is

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
  NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];

  FBSDKShareVideo *video = [[FBSDKShareVideo alloc] init];
  video.videoURL = videoURL;
  FBSDKShareVideoContent *content = [[FBSDKShareVideoContent alloc] init];
  content.video = video;
}
```

Comment: Did you checked in live device?

Comment: Yes, I have been testing my app on device.

Comment: Your code is actually sharing video to facebook news feed instead of messenger. You should do something like: [FBSDKMessengerSharer shareImage:image withOptions:nil]; Please refer to doc here: https://developers.intern.facebook.com/docs/messenger/ios